# Specifying a range for character values in DATALINES in SAS

Tags: sas

In this example:

```
data testfile;
   input x $ y $ 9-17 z $ 19-26; 
   datalines; 
apple   banana    coconut
apple   banana    coconut 
apricot blueberry citron
;
```

What does the 9 -17 and 19- 26 do? These are characters, why are we giving a numeric range?
I picked the example from [SAS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761931.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are the character position in the line to read.  So `y $ 9-17` means that you want to read the 9 character string starting at column 9 and continuing through column 17 into the variable Y.  The `$` is what tells SAS the Y is a character variable and not a number.

Comment: Ok, but when I re ran without these ranges in my data step, the output was the same. So why we need to specify the ranges?

Comment: @Victor You don't in your case - but if you had spaces in your data or similar, you would want to.  Without ranges it defaults to space delimited data; with ranges it's fixed-width.

Comment: Are you sure blueberry was not truncated to $8 when you removed the column indicators?    There are several different input styles or methods, column, formatted, list/delimited, and named.  You could have used any but named to read your data.